# Add items to a model's ManyToMany list in django using AJAX

Tags: ajax, django

I have a model, Profile, with a ManyToManyField. The model it links to is Event. I'm trying to implement an AJAX function that, when executed, will add the details of the Event to the Profile.

My models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank = 'TRUE', primary_key='TRUE')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE')

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        eventList = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my html, I have a link that calls the function like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addEvent({{ name.event_id }}, {{ user.get_profile.id }})">
```

The addEvent function is written like this:

```
function addEvent(id, user){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/addEvent/',
        type: "POST",
        data: {event_id: id, profile: user},
        success: function(data){
            $('hello').html("Yes");
        }
        error: function() {
            $('hello').html("No");
        }
    });
}
```

Finally, my actual view looks as such:

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def addEvent(request):
    event_id = request.POST['event_id']
    user = request.POST['profile']
    event = Event.objects.get(id = event_id)
    user = Profile.objects.get(id = user)
    user.eventList.add(event)

    return HttpResponse(status = 201)
```

Clicking the function-call button, doesn't trigger either the success or error HTML, and after checking the admin site, I know that the event was not added to the eventList. I think my issue lies in the way I'm writing my view and adding to the eventList.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to render a form in your html, including a csrf_token. Then use the javascript onclick javascript to fire the form's submit event.  You can make the form hidden if you don't need the user to edit anything.

Comment: I think this can be done without a form. And I have csrf_exempt decorator on this as well. When I look at the page source, the proper values are filled in for the function call, so just clicking the button should run the function with those values.